Multinomial Logit in R with alternative specific attributes
I would like to ask a question regarding the use of mlogit in R.
When modeling discrete choices using multinominal logit or mixed logit, there are cases where an attribute that makes an alternative attractive does not apply to a competing alternative.
For example, comparing, say a conventional car vs. an electric vehicle (EV), the cost of a component within EV does not exist for a conventional vehicle. Or in the context of travel mode choice, when comparing car only versus two public transportation options, wait time or comfort applies to public transport options but not to car only. How would one use mlogit when attributes vary from one alternative to another? I searched online and the most common advise is to assign NA for the values of attributes that do not apply to an alternative but looks like mlogit does not accept this option.
I would appreciate any feedback.
Regards,
Bob
